# Applying a different color to a ThreeJS shader material at each instance

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to generate a large block of cubes to display some grid data and want to try and have each instance have an edge color as well as a face color. As such I've been implementing an instanced mesh with a shader material.

Here's my shader:

```
<script>

        var vertexShader = `
            varying vec2 vUv;
            void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * instanceMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
            }
        `;
        var fragmentShader = `
                //#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
            
            varying vec2 vUv;
            uniform float thickness;
            uniform vec3 color;
            varying vec3 instanceColor;
            
            float edgeFactor(vec2 p){
                vec2 grid = abs(fract(p - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(p) / thickness;
                return min(grid.x, grid.y);
            }
            
            void main() {
            float a = clamp(edgeFactor(vUv), 0., 1.);
            
            vec3 c = mix(vec3(0), color, a);
            
            gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);
            }
        `;
      
      </script>
```

From which I'm generating this material to use on each instance:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      thickness: {
          value: 1.5
      },
      color: {
          value: new THREE.Color()
      }
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    extensions: {derivatives: true}
  });
```

Then here's the relevant bit of code to create an InstancedMesh. The data I'm trying to plot is in an object array 'cell' that contains positions and dimensions for each box. Each cell[] defines a column of 23 boxes at the same x,z position but at different y positions.

```
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1); 

        const mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material, cell.length * 23);
        scene.add(mesh);

        const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
        let counter = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < cell[i].elevations.length - 1 ; j++){
                let depth = cell[i].elevations[j] - cell[i].elevations[j + 1];
                let zCenterElevation = (depth / 2) + cell[i].elevations[j + 1];
                
                dummy.position.set(cell[i].x, zCenterElevation, -cell[i].y);

                dummy.scale.set(cell[i].width, depth, cell[i].height);
                
                dummy.updateMatrix();
                mesh.setMatrixAt(counter, dummy.matrix);
                
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Which results in something like this:
[image]

How do I add some ability to change the instance shader material color for each box? I've tried looking at mesh.setColorAt(counter, ), but I'm only able to change the color of the whole block. You can do this with THREE.MeshLambertMaterial (or similar) but I can't find a way to do it with a custom shader material.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data of face and edge colors into DataTexture and then process it in shaders:

[image]

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.153.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.153.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
console.clear();

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x202020);
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(3, 5, 8).setLength(15);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
//renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2));

let g = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
g.setAttribute("faceIndex", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  2, 2, 2, 2,
  3, 3, 3, 3,
  4, 4, 4, 4,
  5, 5, 5, 5
], 1));

let colorData = new Float32Array(100 * 6 * 2 * 4); // amount * (faces + edges) * size;
let c = new THREE.Color();
for(let i = 0; i < 100 * 6 * 2; i++){
  c.setHSL(Math.random(), 1, 0.5);
  colorData[i * 4 + 0] = c.r;
  colorData[i * 4 + 1] = c.g;
  colorData[i * 4 + 2] = c.b;
  colorData[i * 4 + 3] = 0;
}
let colorTexture = new THREE.DataTexture(colorData, 100, 12, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType);
colorTexture.needsUpdate = true;

let m = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  vertexColors: true,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.uniforms.colorTexture = {value: colorTexture};
    shader.vertexShader = `
      uniform sampler2D colorTexture;
      attribute float faceIndex;
      varying vec3 vEdgeColor;
      ${shader.vertexShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <color_vertex>`,
      `#include <color_vertex>
        int ii = gl_InstanceID;
        int fi = int(floor(faceIndex + 0.1));
        vColor = texelFetch(colorTexture, ivec2(ii, fi), 0).rgb;
        vEdgeColor = texelFetch(colorTexture, ivec2(ii, fi + 6), 0).rgb;
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
    shader.fragmentShader = `
      varying vec3 vEdgeColor;
      
      // https://madebyevan.com/shaders/grid/
      float getLine(vec2 uv){
          vec2 coord = uv;
          vec2 grid = abs(fract(coord - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(coord) / 3.;
          float line = min(grid.x, grid.y);
          return 1.0 - min(line, 1.0);
      }
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <color_fragment>`,
      `#include <color_fragment>
      
      float line = getLine(vUv);
      diffuseColor.rgb = mix(diffuseColor.rgb, vEdgeColor, line);
      `
    );
    console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  }
});
m.defines = {"USE_UV": ""};

let io = new THREE.InstancedMesh(g, m, 100);

let d = new THREE.Object3D();
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  d.position.random().subScalar(0.5).multiplyScalar(10).round();
  d.updateMatrix();
  io.setMatrixAt(i, d.matrix);
}
scene.add(io);

renderer.setAnimationLoop((_) => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```